# Refreshed images not loading

Tags: objective-c, animation, nsstring, uiimageview, xcode4.3

I have some code in which I have declared 14 images to be displayed in UIImageview and named them as 1,2,3,....14.jpg. These images are in a folder copied from desktop and placed in the project.

Now I have a server and client code running from which the images named 1,2,.... will be refreshed and new images will be coming. But when I try to execute my code can see the images which came for the first time and for every repetition there will be no change in images shown in simulator....

```
    NSArray *array1=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"3.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"4.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"5.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"6.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"7.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"8.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"9.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"10.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"11.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"12.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"13.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"14.jpg"],nil];

[UIImageView beginAnimations:Nil context:NULL];
image1.animationImages=array1;
image1.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
image1.animationDuration=10;
image1.animationRepeatCount=10;
[image1 startAnimating];
```

When this code runs I am getting the same set of 14 images which are shown for the first time. It's not getting changed even though the images are changed in that folder.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for `imageNamed:` says it looks in the application’s main bundle.  Since you can't write to the application bundle on a device, you're not going to be able to replace things that are distributed with the app if you load them that way.

You may want to switch to `imageWithContentsOfFile:` and move your distributed images to a writable location when the app is first run so that you can update them.

(You don't say where you're storing the images that you get from your server.)

Comment: @ phillip ..the solution which u told is not working....i still get the blank screen....

Comment: As a **strategy**, it should be OK.  I'd have to see what your code is doing before I could guess why it's not working in your implementation.

Comment: ok i want to ask a simple question...if i want to show set of images from my system path(/users/Library/Application Support/Apple/iChat Icons/Planets) some thing like this and run them in simulator....how do i define the array...what type of "NS..." should i use and how do i write it....

Comment: This works for me to display one file: `UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/phil/Pictures/AfterRain.png"]; UIImageView *iView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];`.  To build an array of images, just use `imageWithContentsOfFile:` on different paths.  (Check that the paths really exist first!)  Of course, this will **only** work in the simulator.